# Unable to find error sement tree : minimum in subarray

Tags: c++11, tree, segment-tree

I am new to data structures and algo, and unable to find error in my code for the question

Range Minimum Query

Given an array A of size N, there are two types of queries on this array.

1. q l r: In this query you need to print the minimum in the sub-array A[l:r].
2. u x y: In this query you need to update A[x]=y.

Input: First line of the test case contains two integers, N and Q, size of array A and number of queries.

Second line contains N space separated integers, elements of A.
Next Q lines contain one of the two queries.

Output:

For each type 1 query, print the minimum element in the sub-array A[l:r].

Constraints:

```
1 ≤ N,Q,y ≤ 10^5
1 ≤ l,r,x≤N

#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

long a   [100001];
//global array to store input

long tree[400004];  
//global array to store tree

// FUNCTION TO BUILD SEGMENT TREE //////////

void build(long i,long start,long end)  //i = tree node  

{

    if(start==end)

    {
        tree[i]=a[start];

        return;

    }

    long mid=(start+end)/2;

    build(i*2,start,mid);

    build(i*2+1,mid+1,end);

    tree[i] = min(tree[i*2] , tree[i*2+1]);

}

//  FUNCTION TO UPDATE SEGMENT TREE //////////

void update  (long i,long start,long end,long idx,long val)

//idx = index to be updated 

// val = new value to be given at that index

{

    if(start==end)

        tree[i]=a[idx]=val;

    else
    {
        int mid=(start+end)/2;

        if(start <= idx and idx <= mid)

            update(i*2,start,mid,idx,val);

        else

            update(i*2+1,mid+1,end,idx,val);

        tree[i] = min(tree[i*2] , tree[i*2+1]);

    }

}

// FUNCTION FOR QUERY

long query(long i,long start,long end,long l,long r)   
{
    if(start>r || end<l || start > end)

        return INT_MAX;
    else

        if(start>=l && end<=r)

        return tree[i];

    long mid=(start+end)/2;

    long ans1 = query(i*2,start,mid,l,r);
    long ans2 = query(i*2+1,mid+1,end,l,r);

    return min(ans1,ans2);

}

int main()

{

    long n,q;

    cin>>n>>q;

    for(int i=0 ; i<n ; i++)

        cin>>a[i];

    //for(int i=1 ; i<2*n ; i++)    cout<<tree[i]<<"  ";   cout<<endl;

    build(1,0,n-1);

    //for(int i=1 ; i<2*n ; i++)    cout<<tree[i]<<"  ";    cout<<endl;


    while(q--)
    {
            long l,r;


            char ch;

            cin>>ch>>l>>r;

            if(ch=='q')

                cout<<query(1,0,n-1,l-1,r-1)<<endl;

            else

                update(1,0,n-1,l,r);

    }

    return 0;

}
```

Example :input

```
5 15
1 5 2 4 3
q 1 5
q 1 3
q 3 5
q 1 5
q 1 2
q 2 4
q 4 5
u 3 1
u 3 100
u 3 6
q 1 5
q 1 5
q 1 2
q 2 4
q 4 5
```

Expected output:

```
1
1
2
1
1
2
3
1
1
1
4
3
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that all given values assume 1 based indexing: `1 ≤ l,r,x ≤ N`

You chose to build your segment tree with 0 based indexing, so all queries and updates also should use same indexing.

So this part is wrong, because you need to set A[x]=y, and because you use 0 based indexing your code actually sets A[x+1]=y

```
update(1,0,n-1,l,r);
```

To fix change it to this:

```
update(1,0,n-1,l-1,r);
```